# Rails - Mongoid : newly added fields in model giving nil for old data objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I have model as follows:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
end
```

After saving a few user objects to the database I added some more fields:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps::Created
  field :name
  field :birthdate
end
```

Now, I expect I can use the following snippet:

```
@user = User.all
@user.each do |u|
   puts u.name
   puts u.birthdate.strftime(#someFormat)
   puts u.created_at.strftime(#someFormat)
end
```

Unfortunately, because my old `user` objects don't have `birthdate` keys, I receive this error: `strftime called on nil class`.

Question:

- How can I handle such cases with Mongoid? In MySQL, when a column is added it gets added to old rows as well. But if I see in MongoDB, it doesn't add new fields as keys for old data.
- This problem also exists with the `created_at` field as old data doesn't have that field either.

I am looking for good way to solve this, checking for `nil` conditions each time is not a scalable option because the number of fields will continue increasing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also add a default to your new field, which would give all your old records a fallback value.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps::Created

  field :name
  field :birthdate, :type => Date, :default => Date.new(1970,1,1)
end
```

You can update your models which are missing `created_at` values, but just running something simple in your rails console:

```
User.all.each{ |u| u.update_attributes(:created_at => Time.now) if u.created_at.nil? }
```

Answer (score 2):

1) You can check for nil value for those fields:

```
@user = User.all
@user.each do |u|
   puts u.name
   puts u.birthdate.strftime(#someFormat) if u.birthdate
   puts u.created_at.strftime(#someFormat) if u.created_at
end
```

2) You can update all your old models with actual not nil values for those fields. You can do it with mondodb update (read more [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating)) or by writing ruby script like this:

```
User.all.select{|u| u.birthdate.nil? || u.created_at.nil?}.each do |u|
  u.update_attributes(:birthdate => Date.today, :created_at => Time.now)
end
```

birthdate and created_at attributes are filled with sample values.

Comment: any guidelines over writing ruby script with second method ?